# Integrating third party js application to vue.js2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to integrate a third party js application to my vue.js project. It is a molecular editor that will load on my page as a component.
Link to the js application - https://jsme-editor.github.io/dist/index.html
And this is what I want to achive -

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jsme/jsme.nocache.js"></script>
<script>
  //this function will be called after the JavaScriptApplet code has been loaded.
  function jsmeOnLoad() {
     jsmeApplet = new JSApplet.JSME("jsme_container", "380px", "340px");
     jsmeApplet.setAfterStructureModifiedCallback(showEvent);
     document.getElementById("log").value = "";
  }
  function showEvent(event) {
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.value = event.action + " at: " + event.atom + " b: " + event.bond + " m: " + event.molecule + " smiles:" + event.src.smiles() + "\n" + log.value;
  }
</script></head>
<body>
<div id="jsme_container"></div>
<textarea id="log" rows="5" cols="50"> </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have done so far is I have declared it as component as seen below -

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button @click="notify">Notify</button>
    <div id="jsme-container" ref="jsmeContainer"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'newcomp',
    data() {
        return {
            jsmeIsLoaded : false,
            div_select : null
        }
    },
    props: {
        txt: String,
        height: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        width: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        smiles: String,
        options: String,
        onChange: Function
    },
    mounted() {
        let script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = '/home/rathore/Desktop/test_component/src/assets/JSME_2020-12-26/jsme/jsme.nocache.js'
        document.head.appendChild(script)
        this.$nextTick(
            window.jsmeOnLoad = () => {this.jsmeIsLoaded = true;}
        )
    },
    watch: {
        jsmeIsLoaded(){
            this.div_select = this.$refs.jsmeContainer.id
            const div_loader = document.createElement('script')
            const applet_txt = 'jsmeApplet = new JSApplet.JSME("'+this.div_select+'","300px","400px");'
            //console.log(applet_txt,this.div_select)
            const div_applet = document.createTextNode(applet_txt);
            div_loader.appendChild(div_applet);
            document.head.appendChild(div_loader);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //Unused method
        handleJsmeLoad(){
            if (this.props.options){
                this.jsmeApplet = new window.JSApplet.JSME(this.div_select, this.props.width, this.props.height, {options: this.props.options});
            }
            else {
                this.jsmeApplet = new window.JSApplet.JSME(this.div_select, this.props.width, this.props.height);
            }
            this.jsmeApplet.setCallBack("AfterStructureModified", this.handleChange);
            this.jsmeApplet.readGenericMolecularInput(this.props.smiles)
        },

        handleChange(jsmeEvent){
            if (this.props.onChange) {
              this.props.onChange(jsmeEvent.src.smiles())
            }
        },

        notify(){
            if (this.jsmeIsLoaded){
                alert("JSME LOADED!!");
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

and called the component -

App.vue

```
template>
  <div id="app">
    <newcomp :height="'300px'" :width="'400px'" :onChange="logsmile" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import newcomp from './components/NewComponenet.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    newcomp
  },
  methods: {
    logsmile(smiles){
      console.log(smiles)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here I have tried injecting <script> tag in the <head>. It is injected as I expected, but it doesn't work it give me error -
**Uncaught ReferenceError: JSApplet is not defined.** and it doesn't render the editor.
but actually I want it render using *handleJSMELoad()* method. Please suggest me the resolution.

Comment: Hello @GaurabKumarJha, welcome to StackOverflow, I'm trying to assess your situation. So I'm guessing you're starting this project using the generated files and folders from Vue CLI yes?

Comment: Yes @IrfandyJip !! you get it right.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply. Sometimes I don't open SO. I tried checking out the documentation, but I don't seem to see any installation using `npm`. If you're using Vue CLI, you have to install using `npm install [package_name]`. But I don't see any in the docs of `jsme-editor`. Does other library will do?

Comment: You basically confused between `webpack` and "traditional" way of loading `scripts`. Since you don't know about these. I would suggest you to look for another library. It will take a while before you could understand how `webpack` works.